# Should I use a boolean 'confirmed_user' flag, or a Confirmed Users table?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, relational-database

I am wondering which is more correct in database design.
Suppose I have the following mock users table:

```
User
id (big_integer)
name (string)
email (string)
password_digest (string)
confirmed (boolean)
```

The field confirmed is set to TRUE after the user confirms their account through email.
Is this a good design, or should I create a table that holds the confirmed user ids, e.g.:

```
Confirmed User
id (big_integer)
user_id (reference)
```

The same issue faces me when I am adding an 'enabled' field to look-up tables, e.g.:

```
City
id (big_integer)
name (string)
enabled (boolean)
```

Versus:

```
Enabled City
id (big_integer)
city_id (reference)
```

The flag will certainly make selecting the data easier (no joins necessary), but I will be storing all these true/false values when in fact, I can skip that and only store the values corresponding to true with the Confirmed/Enabled table (but here comes joining).

I understand that storing all the boolean values is not significant in memory terms, but I want to know which approach is more correct in database design, and why.

Comment: Both approaches are quite acceptable under particular circumstances.  Your question as states is asking for an opinion, because you haven't provided enough guidance to make a reasonable choice between the approaches.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I have not asked which approach people **think** is correct, I asked for which approach **is** correct in terms of database design. If both approaches are correct (i.e., they do not violate any normalization rules), then that is my answer, thank you.

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. How could it not be? Eg google 'stackoverflow database design Should I use a boolean flag, or two tables'. Always google many clear, concise, specific versions/variants/phrasings of your question/problem/goal/desiderata with & without your specific strings/names/code and read many answers from many questions, which should inform your further googling. If you don't find an answer after applying what you learned and repeating this then ask a question. Use the most frequently productive keywords as tags. Use the best search as a title.

Comment: My current generic comment re "better"/"best" etc: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless *you* define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461

Comment: @philipxy, I seriously tried searching for a similar question before asking, but I was not successful, maybe my vocabulary was not on spot. I will close this question. Thank you.

Comment: You can see that I removed your particular strings but just googled your title the 1st time & picked a duplicate. I knew there would be an older higher voted question so later I googled just once more with 'stackoverflow database design (boolean OR  flag) column vs (two OR new) table' & picked https://stackoverflow.com/q/2538514/3404097 which I see has been deleted. That's just 1 hit each from just 2 queries. (Those googles also have [dba.se] & [softwareengineering.se] hits.) I really mean it when I say in that canned comment, multiply phrase your goal/problem/question clearly etc. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can take either approach depending upon the application requirements.

If all you need is a `true/false` indication for `confirmed`, then consider including it in the `User` table. Set default value to `false` in the `User` table DDL. Update it to `true` when appropriate. This will be a flatter design, requiring no join to find the `confirmed` status for a user.

If you make a separate table `Confirmed_User`, you can use it to maintain a history of when a user's `confirmed` flag was set to `true/false`. This may make sense if a user can have value of `confirmed` change from `true` to `false` and back. You can have a row to record each event. You can track additional details associated with the `confirmation` like `time_of_confirmation`, `description_of_confirmation` etc. This will need a join with the `User` table to get `confirmed` status for a user.

The same logic would apply to `enabled` flag for `City` table.

Comment: Additionally, there may be other data points that only apply to "confirmed" users, and a ConfirmedUser table would be the appropriate place for them.